# Updating range() function in for loop

Tags: python-2.7, iteration

I have the following pseudocode.

```
for j in range(0, len(list)):
    xx
    xx
    if something == True:
        list.append("x")
```

Will `range(0, len(list))` be called every time j iterates through the block of code, and hence will its max value update?

I tried figuring it out looking at the stack data, however I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as `range(0, len(list))` is created once at the beginning to create a list (or iterator in python 3), and then it is just iterated though (using next or indexing). It is equivalent to:

```
list_of_nums = range(0, len(list))  # [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]
for i in list_of_nums:
    j = i[counter]
    ...
```

Use a `while` loop like:

```
j = 0
while j < len(list)):
    xx
    xx
    if something == True:
        list.append("x")
    j += 1
```

Comment: @Vlad Thanks, that's why I use for loops as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

The iterable is only evaluated once. Since `range()` on Python 2.x returns a fixed structure the iteration will never be modified once the looping has started. If you need the iteration to change then you will have to use something that doesn't return a fixed structure, such as iterating over the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

`range` creates a list containing all the element between both arguments - there's nothing magical about it. Once the result is created, it is not modified if the parameters given to `range` are modified, just like any other function.

Assigning the value of `len` to a temporary variable will make this more obvious:

```
tempLen = len(list)
for j in range(0, tempLen):
    xx
    xx
    if something == True:
        list.append("x")
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  `range` is a built-in function.  Calling it returns a list.  The `for` statement holds the first return from `range` and then stops.  Try the following:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for j in range(0, len(l)):
    l.append(j)
    print j
```

It prints three lines.

BTW, it is *not* a good idea to assign a variable to `list`.

Comment: `it is not a good idea to assign a variable to list` Where does he do that?